# Database commit: Which is the preferred way and why?

Tags: python, sql, database, commit

Which one is the preferred way to commit? And what exactly happens internally in both the methods?

## 1:

```
for item in items:
        cursor2.execute(query3, [some_parameter])
        connection1.commit()
```

## 2:

```
for item in items:
        cursor2.execute(query3, [some_parameter])
connection1.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `connection1.commit()` writes the changes to the database.

In the first example, you're commiting every time, which will probably take longer, but which is "safer" (in the event of a crash, more of the data will have been written to the database).

In the second example,you are writing to the database after all the changes have been made.  As this is only one write operation, it will take less time, though technically it is less "safe".

In normal environments, and for short for loops, I'd go with the second one.  If your code takes hours to run, the first method may be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your queries are modifying the data:

The first approach means the database will be updated with your changes on every iteration (item-by-item). The second approach means that there will be only one update, after you finished going through all the items, with all the changes you have made.

The potential problems with the first approach could be:

- data inconsistency if you for some reason did not finish iteration cycle and it was important to have either all of the updates or none of them;
- data inconsistency if someone else queries that dataset while you are in the middle of updating it;
- congestion if you send too many update requests (especially if every one of them is locking one or more tables).

The potential problems with the second approach could be:

- an error due to sending too much data at once;
- someone else could have modified the same data set in a different way and then lose those changes because of your update, which was made on those data in their earlier state. Depending on the transaction isolation level, this could result in either a data inconsistency or your transaction being rejected.

Which approach to choose, depends on the particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

**The method 1**

- will take more time because it must commit the changes to the database item by item;
- it takes more I/O (access to the hard drive);
- if an error occurs in the second query the first query is already commited.

**The method 2**

- will perform faster because it commits the changes only one time;
- It takes less I/O;
- if an error occurs in the second query the first query is rolled back;

The second method is similar to a bulk insert since it commits all the changes only when all queries are executed.